# Merge on date columns

Tags: csv, merge

I think this is a simple problem, but I have not found an answer yet:
I have many **`CSV`** files that I want to merge on column "`End Time`",

```
End Time
2016.03.17 23:30
2016.03.18 21:30
2016.03.20 23:30
2016.03.21 23:30
2016.03.22 23:30
2016.03.23 23:30
2016.03.24 07:30

merged1 = pd.merge( new_df1a, new_df1b, on = 'End Time' )
merged2 = pd.merge( merged1,  new_df1c, on = 'End Time' )
merged3 = pd.merge( merged2,  new_df1d, on = 'End Time' )
```

I want to modify **`End Time`** in the `CSV` file:
`2016.03.23 00:00` to `2016.03.23`
because they don't merge if they don't match exactly.
`2016.03.23 00:30` won't merge with `2016.03.23 00:00`

I think there are two ways:

1. Deleting the clock time entries `00:00` after the date for all `CSV`
2. Merge only on the date for example `2016.03.23` for all `CSV` files.
   The date entry changes from day to day.

Erasing the clock time could be done by this:

```
df1b = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Chris/AppData/Roaming/MetaQuotes/Terminal/A6DFBB1B8DE9672D2328FF3445436DEC/MQL4/Files/MetaTrader - ActivTrades/MP - Multi Composite Profiles-v2.1/AUDCAD/0000-2359/Overlay-3Days-PriceSteps-1.MinDistPrices-4.MinDistTPOs-3.csv")

df1b.rename(columns={"Range" : "R3audcad"}, inplace=True)

keep_cols = [ "End Time","R3audcad"]

new_df1b = df1b[keep_cols]

new_df1b['End Time'].map(lambda x: str(x)[:-5])

new_df1b.to_csv("C:/Users/Chris/AppData/Roaming/MetaQuotes/Terminal/A6DFBB1B8DE9672D2328FF3445436DEC/MQL4/Files/MetaTrader - ActivTrades/MP - Multi Composite Profiles-v2.1/VAs/va3audcad.csv", index=False)

df1b = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Chris/AppData/Roaming/MetaQuotes/Terminal/A6DFBB1B8DE9672D2328FF3445436DEC/MQL4/Files/MetaTrader - ActivTrades/MP - Multi Composite Profiles-v2.1/VAs/va3audcad.csv")
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you checked the intermediate representation after `( lambda x: str(x)[:-5] )`? There should be `[:-6]` so as to terminate at **`YYYY.MM.DD`** sharp, without a trailing space. My approach would be to first process / "convert" plain **`CSV`** ASCII-files with powers of **`np.loadtxt()`** dict-of-lambdas facility and save these on disk, finally let `pandas` start it's work with already fine-tuned files.

Comment: Yes, maybe. The problem was: new_df1b['End Time'].map(lambda x: str(x)[:-5]). It must be df1b=df1b['End Time'].map(lambda x: str(x)[:-5]) and before the kepp_cols operation. Thanx for your help